# How cut part of movie in php

Tags: php, flv

User can upload any movie (.mov .mpg .avi .flv and many more) And now i would like cut this file from 15 to 25 seconds (part will be 10 seconds only) and convert this small part to FLV as preview of movie.

Now i have some questions:

1. Should i convert all uploaded movie to flv ? or cut part only and all movie file make as zip ?
2. How can i cut this file in php 7 ? is it possible ? i found

   `ffmpeg -ss [start] -i in.mp4 -t [duration] -c copy out.mp4`

but this is only for mp4 ?

Comment: don't convert to `flv` at all use `mp4`, you can run your shell command with  `shell_exec(command);` from your php script

Comment: so if i get *.avi then convert to mp4  ?

Comment: yup, that way you can play them on your website with just the `<video>` tag

Answer (score 0):

For HTML5 you can output various formats for compatibility. For example, H.264 + AAC in MP4, H.265/HEVC + AAC in MP4, and VP9 + Opus in Webm:

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i input \
  -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart h264.mp4 \
  -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart h265.mp4 \
  -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 2000k -c:a libopus vp9.webm
```

Adjust `-preset`, `-crf`, anf `-b:v` to your needs. Implementing this into `shell_exec` should be trivial for those familiar with PHP.

See the following FFmpeg Wiki articles for more info: [PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP), [H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265), [VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9).

Comment: i will testing now